# bash: combine five lines of input to each line of output

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a input file as follows:

```
MB1 00134141 
MB1 12415085 
MB1 13253590
MB1 10598105
MB1 01141484
...
...
MB1 10598105
```

I want to combine 5 lines and merge it into one line.
I want my bash script to process the bash script to produce output as follows -

```
MB1 00134141 MB1 12415085 MB1 13253590 MB1 10598105 MB1 01141484
...
...
...
```

I have written following script and it works but it is slow for file of size 23051 lines.
Can I write a better code to make it faster?

```
#!/bin/bash
file=timing.csv
x=0
while [ $x -lt $(cat $file | wc -l) ]
do
   line=`head -n $x $file | tail -n 1`
   echo -n $line " "
   let "remainder = $x % 5"
   if [ "$remainder" -eq 0 ] 
   then
        echo ""
   fi
   let x=x+1
done
exit 0
```

I tried to execute the following command but it messes up some numbers.

```
cat timing_deleted.csv | pr -at5
```

Comment: Just saving the value of `cat $file | wc -l` before the loop instead of calling it each time through the loop should speed things up.

Comment: I am wondering why `pr -at5 timing_deleted.csv` didn't work... it works very well when I tried and pretty fast.. did the file have dos style line ending or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure bash, with no external processes (for speed):

```
while true; do
  out=()
  for (( i=0; i<5; i++ )); do
    read && out+=( "$REPLY" )
  done
  if (( ${#out[@]} > 0 )); then
    printf '%s ' "${out[@]}"
    echo
  fi
  if (( ${#out[@]} < 5 )); then break; fi
done <input-file >output-file
```

This correctly handles files where the number of lines is not a multiple of 5.

Comment: the other answer below is a hell of a lot better, `cat input_file | tr "\n" " "`

Comment: @charneykaye, the OP says they want to combine batches of **five** lines, not **all** lines. Read the question.

Comment: That's a good point, Charles-- IMO the question title "bash script output multiple lines on single line" ought to be edited to reflect exactly this.  Otherwise, the below answer is most useful to those (like myself) who are asking the simple question.

Answer (score 8):

Using tr:

```
cat input_file | tr "\n" " "
```

Comment: Useless use of cat: This would be better written as `tr '\n' ' ' <input_file`, giving `tr` a direct file handle on the input file, rather than a pipeline to a different process that reads the input file.

Comment: Also, this doesn't fulfill the question's requirements: It combines **all** the input into one line, rather than combining five lines of input into each line of output.

Comment: This does not fulfill the questions requirement

Answer (score 5):

Use the paste command:

```
 paste -d ' ' - - - - - < tmp.txt
```

---

`paste` is far better, but I couldn't bring myself to
delete my previous `mapfile`-based solution.

[UPDATE: `mapfile` reads too many lines prior to version [4.2.35](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.2-patches/bash42-035) when used with `-n`]

```
#!/bin/bash
file=timing.csv
while true; do
    mapfile -t -n 5 arr
    (( ${#arr} > 0 )) || break
    echo "${arr[*]}"
done < "$file"
exit 0
```

We can't do `while mapfile ...; do` because `mapfile` exists with status 0 even when it doesn't read any input.

Comment: Yes this works fine ! Only for the variation in the length of each number, the output was seen to have irregular spaces or tabs. 
But it works correctly ! :)
Thanks !

Comment: paste should work fine; there is a small bug in the mapfile-based solution that I will fix.

Comment: Nice -- I'm embarrassed that I didn't think of using paste myself.

Answer (score 3):

Using sed, but this one will not process last few lines that do not add to a factor of 5:

```
 sed 'N;N;N;N;s/\n/ /g;' input_file
```

The `N` command reads the next line and appends it to the current line, preserving the newline. This script reads four additional lines for each line it reads, accumulating chunks of 5 lines in the buffer. For each such chunk, it replaces all of the newlines with a space.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xargs`, if your input always contains a consistent number of spaces per line:

```
cat timing_deleted.csv | xargs -n 10
```

This will take the input from `cat timing_deleted.csv` and combine the input on 10 (`-n 10`) whitespace characters. The spaces in each column, such as `MB1 00134141`, count as a whitespace character - as well as the newline at the end of each line. So, for 5 lines, you'll need to use 10.

**EDIT**
As commented by Charles, you can skip the usage of `cat` and directly push the data into `xargs` with:

```
xargs -n 10 < timing_deleted.csv
```

I didn't notice any performance gains using a really large file, but it doesn't require multiple commands.

Comment: This one works, but I can see that its slow as compared to the SED. Perhaps because its running two processes and piping the output.
Thanks for the solution !

Comment: @RajTendulkar Yeah, that's a worthy point; however, and I'm not knocking the other solution - it's a good one, but this one won't miss the last few lines if they do not add up to an even 5 (unless you pass in the `-x` option too, of course).

Comment: No reason for `cat` here: `xargs -n 10 <timing_deleted.csv`

Answer (score 1):

A awk script would do that. A sed replace too, I guess. I don't know sed well, so here you go.

```
NF{ 
    if(i>=5){
        line = line "\n";
        i=0;
    }else{
        line = line " " $0;
        i++;
    }
}

END{
    print line;
}
```

Call that, say, merge.awk. Here is how you invoque it :

```
    awk -f merge.awk filetomerge.txt
```

or
       `cat filetomerge.txt | awk -f merge.awk`

Should be rather fast too.

Comment: Or if you prefer obfuscated awk: `awk ORS=NR%5\?FS:RS` :)

Comment: I did it that way because it is faster to print only once in terminal, but not sure it makes much sense anymore. Some awk mechanismes are still obscure to me... Good to know.

Comment: Aye, there's not much to gain on buffering the entire input. Also, if the input is larger than available memory, your awk will fail.