# Pick 20 records each time and transpose from a big file

Tags: loops, unix, awk, sed

I have a big file with 1 column and 800,000 rows

Example:

```
123

234

...

5677

222

444
```

I want to transpose it into 20 numbers per line.

Example:

```
123,234,....

5677,
222,
444,....
```

I tried using while loop like this

```
while [ $(wc -l < list.dat) -ge 1 ]

do

cat list.dat | head -20 | awk -vORS=, '{ print $1 }'| sed 's/,$/\n/' >> sample1.dat

sed -i -e '1,20d' list.dat

done
```

but this is insanely slow.

Can anyone suggest a faster solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pr` is the right tool for this, for example:

```
$ seq 100 | pr -20ats,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60
61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80
81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
```

For your file, try `pr -20ats, list.dat`

Based on width of column text, you might run into the error `pr: page width too narrow`. In that case, try:

```
$ seq 100000 100100 | pr -40ats,
pr: page width too narrow

$ seq 100000 100100 | pr -J -W79 -40ats,
100000,100001,100002,100003,100004,100005,100006,100007,100008,100009,100010,100011,100012,100013,100014,100015,100016,100017,100018,100019,100020,100021,100022,100023,100024,100025,100026,100027,100028,100029,100030,100031,100032,100033,100034,100035,100036,100037,100038,100039
100040,100041,100042,100043,100044,100045,100046,100047,100048,100049,100050,100051,100052,100053,100054,100055,100056,100057,100058,100059,100060,100061,100062,100063,100064,100065,100066,100067,100068,100069,100070,100071,100072,100073,100074,100075,100076,100077,100078,100079
100080,100081,100082,100083,100084,100085,100086,100087,100088,100089,100090,100091,100092,100093,100094,100095,100096,100097,100098,100099,100100
```

Formula for `-W` value is `(col-1)*len(delimiter) + col` where `col` is number of columns required

From `man pr`

> pr - convert text files for printing
>
> -a, --across
>         print columns across rather than down, used together with -COLUMN
>
> -t, --omit-header
>         omit page headers and trailers; implied if PAGE_LENGTH <= 10
>
> -s[CHAR], --separator[=CHAR]
>         separate columns by a single character, default for CHAR is the   character  without  -w  and  'no
>         char'  with  -w.   -s[CHAR]  turns  off line truncation of all 3 column options (-COLUMN|-a -COLUMN|-m)
>         except -w is set
>
> -COLUMN, --columns=COLUMN
>         output COLUMN columns and print columns down, unless -a is used. Balance number of lines in the columns
>         on each page
>
> -J, --join-lines
>         merge full lines, turns off -W line truncation, no column alignment, --sep-string[=STRING] sets separa‐
>         tors
>
> -W, --page-width=PAGE_WIDTH
>         set page width to PAGE_WIDTH (72) characters always, truncate lines, except -J option is set, no inter‐
>         ference with -S or -s

See also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to use any other external binaries, you can refer the below SO link answering a similar question in depth.

[bash: combine five lines of input to each line of output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075260/bash-combine-five-lines-of-input-to-each-line-of-output)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sed:

```
sed -n '21~20 { x; s/^\n//; s/\n/, /g; p;}; 21~20! H;' list.dat
```

The first command

```
21~20 { x; s/^\n//; s/\n/, /g; p;},
```

is triggered at lines matching 21+(n*20); n>=0. Here everything that was put in the hold space at complement lines via the second command:

```
21~20! H;
```

is processed:

```
x;
```

puts the content of the hold buffer (20 lines) in the pattern space and places the current line (21+(n*20)) in the hold buffer. In the pattern space:

```
s/^\n//
```

removes the trailing new line and:

```
s/\n/, /g
```

does the desired substitution.:

```
p;
```

prints the now 20-columned row.
After that the next line is read in the hold buffer and the process continues.